# Using PHP str_replace in a search function doesn't return desired results

Tags: php

In my search function i use the code below:

```
$mSearch =  Search::newInstance();
$query_results = (array) json_decode($mSearch->toJson());
$pattern = $query_results['sKeyword'];

$query_results['sKeyword'] = str_replace(' ', '*', $pattern) . '*';
```

When i search for the keyword **"phone"** its returns the results correct.
When i search for the keyword **"pho"** its also returns the results correct.

But when i search for the keyword **"phones"** its returns zero results.

What i have to change in this code,

```
$query_results['sKeyword'] = str_replace(' ', '*', $pattern) . '*';
```

so the search also return results that contains ANY of the letters in the keyword "phones"?

Comment: are you sure that you have `phones` string in your searching string ?

Comment: Hi. yes i m sure !!

Comment: there is no code you shared where comparison happens .

Comment: str_ireplace($array1,$array2,$string)